# Convert Excel to Word and then again in Excel from Word

Tags: php, excel, ms-word

I've an Excel file which is in hindi kruti and I wanted to convert it in mangal but there is no any software or tools which provide it, but it works for Word so is it any way to convert that Excel file to Word so I can convert it to kruti to mangal and then again convert it to Excel in same format ???

Comment: are you just changing character sets?

Comment: yes because it shows in windows 7 but not in xp and there are many people who use xp so i must have to change it

Comment: *StrConv* function to convert a Unicode string to an ANSI string.

 StrConv("ABCDEFG", vbFromUnicode) // vbFromUnicode - 64, like that can work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing character sets is a job for [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) ... export your excel as csv, import into php and use iconv to change character sets, and then export as csv.   then you can import the csv into excel.